# Не срабатывает запрос ajax к php скрипту

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Не могу понять в чем моя ошибка. Со страницы идет ajax-запрос на jQuery к php скрипту (версия php - 7.1). Для этого примера я упростил его до предела, но все равно - толку 0:

```
function init_get2(){
$('a.ajaxArticleBodyByGet2').one('click', function(){
    var content = $(this).attr("data-contentId");
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: '/ajax/showContentsHandler.php?articleId=' + content,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data){
            console.log('Ответ получен', data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
            hideLoaderIdentity();
            console.log('ajaxError xhr: ' + xhr + ', ' + 'ajaxError status: ' + status +
                    ', ' + 'ajaxError error: ' + error); 
        }
    });
});
}
```

Ловит данный запрос простейший php скрипт:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['articleId'])) {
    echo "hello world";
}

?>
```

Вроде все элементарно, даже писать сюда такой вопрос как-то стыдно...Однако код не работает. И как я могу понять, даже не доходит до php. Выводится ошибка и никакие проверки на стороне php не срабатывают. Новичок в ajax - понимаю что не оправдание но все таки. )

Comment: Попробуй указать полный путь к скрипту

Comment: А до отправки ajax доходит?

Comment: Какая ошибка выводится? Что показывают логи веб-сервера (отражается ли там запрос)?

Comment: Вы данную функцию где-то вызвали?

Comment: Функцию, конечно, вызывал, причем прописывая её таким образом : $(function(){ init_get2(); }); То-есть, как я понимаю, jquery точно подключился. "А до отправки ajax доходит?" - а вот как проверить дошел ли ajax до отправки я не знаю. "Какая ошибка выводится?"  Согласно моему коду обработки ошибок выводится следующее: "ajaxError xhr: [object Object], ajaxError status: error, ajaxError error: "

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего ошибка 404, попробуйте открыть этот url напрямую в браузере или указать полный путь. Например:

```
URL: 'http://localhost/ajax/showContentsHandler.php?articleId=' + content
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за версии, решение нашлось ) Дело в том, что я привязал данную функцию к клику по ссылке, предварительно не отменив её поведение по умолчанию. Строчка onclick="event.preventDefault()" решила проблему.